# Plotting solutions to Solve for various parameter values

Tags: equation-solving

I want to plot the solutions to *Solve* for various values of the parameter *m*. The trouble is that I can't simply find the solution in terms of *m*, and then use *Table* and *ListLinePlot*, because for some values of *m* my quartic reduces to a quadratic and so then I get division by zero when I substitute  *m* into the general solution. So what I need to do is have the code sub in different values of m into *Solve*, prior to solving. I was thinking I might want to use some kind of for loop but I wasn't sure the best way to code this in Mathematica. Any suggestions? Below are the equations I am subbing into *Solve*.

```
bet = 0.001
fc1 = (2/8)^2;
fc2 = (3/8)^2
N1p = N1*(1 - m) + N2*m;
N2p = N2*(1 - m) + N1*m;
b1 = 1 - bet*N1p - fc1;
b2 = 1 - bet*N2p - fc2;
ans = Solve[{N1 == N1p*b1*2, N2 == N2p*b2*2}, {N1, N2}]
```

I would like to plot m for values between 0 and 1, and I am only interested in the real solutions.

Comment: Neither `d` nor `alph` appear in the equations.   No effort  to ask a reliable question.

Comment: Sorry, I missed d and alph. In what other ways could I make this question more reliable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't say what range you want, and when $m<0.3$, there are multiple solutions, but you might want to do something like this?

```
ans = Table[
   Solve[{N1 == N1p*b1*2, N2 == N2p*b2*2}, {N1, N2}, Reals][[2]], {m, 
    0.3, 20, 0.1}];

ListPlot[{N1, N2} /. ans]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

```
bet = 1/1000;
fc1 = (2/8)^2;
fc2 = (3/8)^2;
N1p = N1*(1 - m) + N2*m;
N2p = N2*(1 - m) + N1*m;
b1 = 1 - bet*N1p - fc1;
b2 = 1 - bet*N2p - fc2;

ans = {N1, N2} /. 
    Solve[{N1 == N1p*b1*2, N2 == N2p*b2*2}, {N1, N2}, Reals] // 
   Simplify;

Grid[
 Partition[
  ParametricPlot[#, {m, -20, 20},
     Frame -> True, Axes -> False,
     FrameLabel ->
      (Style[#, Bold, 14] & /@ {"N1", "N2"}),
     PlotPoints -> 150,
     AspectRatio -> 1,
     ImageSize -> 252] & /@ ans, 2]]
```

[image]